# How to set minimum bar width of C3 Bar chart.

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I want to set minimum bar width of C3 Bar chart and the spacing between them using ratio. I am trying to set minimum width of single bar rather than the whole chart.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#div1',  
  data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
        }
        // or
        //width: 100 // this makes bar width 100px
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" />
 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: What is your specific requirement @Raichu

Comment: @Dinesh- specifically I just want to set minimum width of each bar of the C3 bar chart. By defualt it is responsive and bar width automatically sets for each bar according to the conatainer width. Here m trying to set minimum width of each bar of the chart. I hope you get my idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using

```
bar: {
  width: {
    ratio: 0.2
  }
}
```

the default value is 0.6, You can change the width of bars by changing this value but bar to bar spacing will be constant.